# jump to a specific location within a page having STICKY MENU

Tags: css, html

i am trying to build a website..i am using a "sticky menu" concept which automatically minimizes its height after certain scroll..now the problem is when there is a jump within a page,the sticky menu covers half the content on jump!

for example..look at this website:
   type in---"www.sitnlearnit.com" in your address bar...
  in that website,when we navigate through "COURSES OFFERED" item and select any list   item,we are supposed to jump to that location! it is happening..but the content is covered by sticky menu..

how to solve this???

Comment: Could you add some example HTML and CSS (minimum reproducible code sample) to show the problem?

Comment: it is right there in the website which i have mentioned! www.sitnlearnit.com

Comment: People are more likely to be able to help if you can edit your question to include the specific code, without having to go to other sites (which may not be around in the future) or do detective work on a third-party for you. Here's some advice on adding code samples to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: In addition, I'm on my work computer and I'm not going to go to any site I don't know ;)

Answer (score 0):

Design the site so that the area where the sticky menu will be will never have content in it - wherever the menu moves in that space, there will never be content to cover up.